# How to run a python script in a specific directory automatically?

Tags: cron, scripting

I have a python script that I wish to run at 5pm every Friday.
How can I achieve that ?

I understand I could do this through cron. However, as I have used relative file paths in the Python script and therefore must be run in the specific directory with the other files. I have seen I may be able to achieve this using the pipe operator however I have been unable to find an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this , I will list just 2 ways :

(1) Use a Bash "Wrapper Shell Script" in your Cron Job to Execute @ 5PM.
In the "Wrapper Script" , first "cd X" where X is the necessary Directory.
Then Execute the Python Script. It will run in the Directory X.

```
# My Bash Wrapper Script  
cd X # use the necessary Directory here  
python MyPythonScript.py
```

(2) In your Python Script , import module "os" & use "os.chdir" to Change Directory & then continue with the Python Script.

```
# My Python Script  
import os  
os.chdir(X) # use necessary Directory here  
# continue with Python Script  
# no other Changes necessary
```

These 2 ways are very easy to use.

Comment: these shebang lines are invalid

Comment: I wanted to use Comments , though typing habit made those accidental shebangs. I have made the Corrections , @GeraldSchneider , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just cd into the directory before running the script.

```
0 17 * * Fri cd /path/to/dir && python myscript.py
```

No wrapper necessary.

Comment: There are various other ways too. I did not want to include this , because I have sometimes come across Cases where the cron line was too cumbersome , when the Parameters were complex , with single quotes , double quotes & escape sequences. I usually took all that complexity , put it into a Wrapper Script & kept the cron line simple !